# DirectoryEntry and Domain Controller

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryentry, domaincontroller, directorysearcher

We had a script in Powershell where we manipulated the Active Directory. I programmed it now in C#. My collegues say that they had to specify the domain controller in PS because otherwise it can happen that you read with DC A and write on DC B which could cause problems.

**Do I really have to specify the Domain Controller if I'm using DirectorySearcher to find an entry and manipulate it? Or does per definition the same Domain Controller is user for finding the object (DirectorySearcher) and saving it (CommitChanges)?**

I do not think so, since I can only specify it in the searching part (DirectoryEntry object for the DirectorySearcher) but not when it is written back to the AD (CommitChanges). So I suppose that the same DC is used for writing like the one used for reading.

Below I have an example where I search for a specific entry and change a property.

```
string filter = "(proxyaddresses=SMTP:johndoe@abc.com)";
string searchOU = "ou=Users,dc=abc,dc=com";

DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + searchOU);
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
search.Filter = filter;
SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
search.Dispose();
entry.Close();

DirectoryEntry toContact = result.GetDirectoryEntry();    
toContact.Properties["showInAddressBook"].Value = addressbook; 
toContact.CommitChanges();
toContect.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might I recommend using the objects available in the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace?  It's a more recent addition to .NET and handles AD work much more gracefully. It's recently saved me a whole lot of heartache which the older DirectorySearcher way of doing things was in part causing.  Let the framework take the strain!  There are lots of really useful articles around on the web, such as [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38344/Using-System-DirectoryServices-AccountManagement).

As an example of how to use PrincipalContext for searching Active directory, try this:

```
var adContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
var queryTemplateUser = new UserPrincipal(adContext);
queryTemplateUser.SamAccountName = "HenryCrunn";
var ldapSearcher = new PrincipalSearcher(queryTemplateUser);
var searchResults = ldapSearcher.FindAll();
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13612911)

Comment: Yes you're quite right of course.  Apologies, I'll update the answer with some useful code.

Comment: @DrMistry: A guy from Microsoft asked me to use DirectorySearcher because it is more flexible. The problem is that the link also does not answer the question about the domain controller. Does the objects in 'searchResults' "remeber" which DC they used to find the object and use the same if I update the found objects? BTW: Watch out when using FindAll() you have to dispose the found objects othewise you have a memory leak.

Comment: You can get the name of the connected server from the PrincipalContext.ConnectedServer, I would assume that would be the DC which actions all requests.

Comment: If I get you right you also think it's the same DC. Is there a way to check this or is this somewhere documented?

Comment: Well my understanding is that the connection to the server is made on instantiation and persists until the PrincipalContext is disposed, so it should be the same DC for the lifetime of the object.

Comment: @DrMistry Thank you - Sounds good! (Sorry I over saw this comment!)